# Plot surface in cylindrical coordinate system in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, cylindrical

I have a function and want to plot it on cylindrical coordinate.

```
w(z,theta)=sin(n.pi.z/a).sin(m.theta)
```

The limits of variables are: z=0..a , theta=0..theta_0 and radius of cylinder is  R=1.

As a physical sense I can explain that if we in the Cartesian coordinate,
z & theta are x,y axis and w is surface on this rectangular domain. But in cylindrical coordinate z & theta restrict one cylindrical piece of cylinder with radius=1 that w is surface on this domain.

Answer (score 2):

Plotting using cylindrical or spherical coordinates involves several steps:

1. Create vectors for `theta` and `z`:

   theta = linspace(0,2*pi);
   z = linspace(0,10);
2. Create a `meshgrid` from `theta` and `z`:

   [TH,Z] = meshgrid(theta,z);
3. Write your function R(TH,Z):

   R = sin(Z)+1+5*sin(TH); %// For cylinder it would be simply R = ones(size(Z));
4. Convert cylindrical coordinates to cartesian:

   [x,y,z] = pol2cart(TH,R,Z);
5. Plot the result using `surf`, `mesh` or whatever:

   mesh(x,y,z);
   axis equal

This is the result you get:
[image]

Comment: Is there any way the color code can be based on the radial distance from z axis instead of being based on z axis, please?